# The difference between 'have' family words

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between:

> I **have** a car.
>   I **possess** a car.
>   I **own** a car.
>
> The car **features** heating system.
>   The car **has** heating system.
>   The car **possesses** a heating system.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times that these words are interchangeable but they all carry subtle differences, and to be honest, the meanings could shift a little depending on the situation.

"***I have a car***" suggests that a car is available to you. In some situations, it could mean that you have the car with you. For example, if someone said "*we need to take a ride into town right now*" and you replied "*I have a car*" it would be assumed that the car is available to jump into right now. However you could also say "*I have a car but it is at home*". But it doesn't always mean that. You could say "*I have car, but it's my dad's*". "Have" doesn't really determine ownership.

"***I own a car***" is very specifically talking about ownership. It doesn't really say anything about where the car is or its availability. In fact you could say "*I own a car, but it's in the garage right now*".

"***I possess a car***" is not really a phrase I have heard. "Possession" really implies that something is in your control. It *can* imply ownership, but not necessarily. For example, if you loan something that you own to somebody else, you still *own* it but they *possess* it. There is even a saying that "possession is 9/10ths of the law", which implies that it is easier to prove you own something if you possess it, and harder to prove if you don't.

In your secondary examples of a car, the example of "*the car possesses a heating system*" is just incorrect, as would be "*the car owns...*", because a car is an inanimate object and incapable of ownership of anything. Either of the two other examples "*the car has....*" or "*the car features...*" would be just fine.

Comment: The one difference between _has_ and _features_ is that _features_ refers to something good about the car, whereas _has_ can refer to something positive or negative. I can say, “The car features a heating system,” but, unless I am trying to be humorous, I wouldn’t say, “The car features a dent in the driver’s-side door,” or, “The car features a bad muffler.”

Comment: What about 'concepts'? Can we say: 'The new approach features the capability of ...' or 'The method feature the advantage of ... '